# Testing spring-cloud-stream with their test-binder always throws MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: testing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

I'm trying to write tests for my message producers. But whenever i try to send a message using the injected Bindings i get following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=..., headers={spanTraceId=0761b2d61b665041, spanId=e3b298682fefe198, spanParentSpanId=549ea87126d2484d, nativeHeaders={X-B3-TraceId=[0761b2d61b665041], spanTraceId=[0761b2d61b665041], X-B3-SpanId=[e3b298682fefe198], spanId=[e3b298682fefe198], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[549ea87126d2484d], spanParentSpanId=[549ea87126d2484d], X-B3-Sampled=[0], spanSampled=[0]}, X-B3-SpanId=e3b298682fefe198, X-B3-ParentSpanId=549ea87126d2484d, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=0761b2d61b665041, id=0c885a37-a1b1-fc0a-1314-e403ec1bffdb, spanSampled=0, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1589551815143}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    ... 42 more
```

Since I'm testing the message producers there naturaly are no consumers in my code. How can i fix this exception?

Here is a minimal test class i created that shows the same behaviour:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MessagingTest.SampleConfiguration.class, Application.class, EventMockConfiguration.class})
public class MessagingTest {

    @Autowired
    private LibraryMessageSource libraryMessageSource;

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        libraryMessageSource.creations().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    @Import({TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class})
    public static class SampleConfiguration {

    }
}
```

Note: Application.class the main class for my app and EventMock overwrites a bean in the context with a specific mock.

```
public interface LibraryMessageSource {

    String LIBRARY_CREATE = "messages-library-create";
    String LIBRARY_UPDATE = "messages-library-update";

    @Input(LIBRARY_CREATE)
    MessageChannel creations();

    @Input(LIBRARY_UPDATE)
    MessageChannel updates();
}
```

Comment: The binder is the consumer in this case; you need to show your test code.

Comment: @GaryRussell i added a minimal test class i use for debugging an that i believe is supposed to work.

Comment: Please post a complete minimal project someplace that exhibits this behavior so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @GaryRussell i created a sample with similar versions i have to use: https://github.com/Laures/messaging-error-binder-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I'm testing the message producers

Your application has a consumer, not a producer

```java
    @Input(INPUT)
    MessageChannel events();
```

and you have no `@StreamListener` subscribed to it.

```java
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        libraryMessageSource.events().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    }
```

Comment: You are correct, after changing the annotations from input to output the everything makes more sense and actually works.